# How can I use preg_match to match integer or double

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match numbers like 1-9 or double number like 3.65 etc.
I have used the following but no good result

```
$number = 2.3;
preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9.][0-9]{1,2}/", $number);
```

Anyone to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex like this `([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?`.

`([0-9]+)` will match integer or digits before dot in double.

`(\.[0-9]+)?` will match dot and digits after that in double but have to use it with `?` because it's optional.

Comment: what if I want the whole thing to be optional

Comment: I have figured it out